# SE: User Experience - appropriate for interface design review?

Tags: discussion, design

I'm a web developer and interface designer, and for the improvement of my development structure and practice, I can go to SE's Code Review. However, even more than I focus on the quality of back-end design, I focus, in extreme-detail, on developing the best possible user interface for the software. Not just something to get the job done, but truly inspirational, beautiful, interactive user interface built to satisfy the consumer at every level.

---

I can ask opinions and reviews of these interfaces from clients, family, and friends, but I feel that while they like the interfaces, they aren't able to give the high level review/ criticism that might help me to improve my practices further.

---

- I'm wondering if this site is a place where it would be appropriate for me to request these reviews, similar to the way code quality is reviewed in detail on Code Review.
- If not, maybe there is another site known for this by the design community?

---

Thanks for your time!

I've also asked [this very same question on SE: Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/940/se-graphic-design-appropriate-for-interface-design-review?noredirect=1#comment2709_940), where it was suggested that while user-interface review meets guidelines there, it would be interesting to see how UX responds to the request.

I would, of course, like to know which site/community is *better suited* for such review requests.

Answer (score 4):

When flagging for off-topic this is one of the flags:

> Questions about Site Reviews are off-topic because questions here are expected to be relevant for a variety of people in the same situation. Reviewing a site, flow or interface only helps one person at a specific time. Instead try to ask a focused question about a particular aspect of the design that solicits solutions, not opinions.

Since yours is a site review, it would be considered off-topic.

[The Forrst community](http://www.forrst.com) used to be a place where you could get honest feedback on your design (although lacking people with real UX skills). But since the 8th of april they disabled the posting and are saying to change things.
It's a shame, because sites like Dribbble and Behance will only get you a thumbs up and a "good job" and not the constructive feedback you're looking for.
I don't really know which direction Forrst is going, so you could keep an eye on that community, but other than that I don't know any active communities that deliver constructive feedback on your designs. Be sure to let me know if you find one.

Comment: Thank you Paul, an intuitive, to-the-point answer. Now, Code Review is based on the unusual principle of review, rather tha question answering, (not accepted by most/any other SE sites) and it works because developers enjoy looking at good code and thus improving their own practices. Similarly, artists / designers might appreciate a similar site for the same reasons. I wonder if the demand is high enough for a new site...

Comment: @jt0dd You've got at least one vote

Comment: The trouble with comparing to code review is that CR answers can be 'correct' at least in a demonstrably and measurable way. 'Review My Site' requests are far more subjective.

Comment: @JonW that has always been the same with Forrst. It shouldn't be answers, but suggestions and it should be up to the OP to make use of those suggestions or not.

Comment: Yes, as a site idea in it's own right it's fine. Just that it's not really ideal for a Stack Exchange site. It looks like @jt0dd has [submitted a proposal to Area51 for just this idea](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/67793/design-review) so we'll see how well that's received.

Comment: I agree it's not ideal for SE. It should be stand-alone

Comment: @JonW At the same time, the very same way that coding practices are often extremely opinion-based (and often controversial), Graphic Design tequniques and practices are no more or less opinion based. A person can have as much personal style in his code as he can in his interface design. I think in this way and others, the concept is not different at all from Code Review.

Comment: But yes, as you said, we'll see how it's received.

Comment: @jt0dd: It really comes down to [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) really. Other StackExchange Review proposals don't tend to go down too well, see [Product Reviews](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66630/product-reviews)

Comment: @JonW That is a very bad comparison, I think :/ The idea there is terrible. They are asking for reviews of existing products, not personal, intellectually subjective works to be looked at and reviewed on a page. Have a look at the arguments supporting a design review site, just to see it a bit more fully from the perspective of a graphic designer. http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/14124/do-you-think-that-a-code-review-style-site-for-graphic-designers-will-be-support

Comment: At any rate! Once you get into serious graphic design, you find that design is not so much different from code at all... You can crowd the interface just like you can write unnecessary code, and you can write pointless, inefficient code just like you can design an ugly character. I'm just saying that the two are more alike than you imagine.